# Problem With Coded JavaScript Won't Replace Element After 3 Clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, replace

Been coding this javascript code for some while was in motivation of replacing adsense code manually, when users click on the ad 3 times the adsense ad replaces its `data-ad-slot="4092520690"` value with `data-ad-slot="9092520690"`. So far i've coded some steps on how that could be possible with JavaScript code but it doesn't seem to work simply for no reason. This is the element, I am trying to trigger the javascript code on `<ins data-ad-slot="4092520690">ins</ins>`

Here is what, I coded so far for it, I would greatly appreciate if someone could enlighten the problems for me:

```js
function replaceAfter3Clicks(elem, newElem) {
  let count = 0;
  let callback = function() {
    count++;
    if (count === 3) {
      elem.parentNode.replaceChild(newElem, elem);
    }
    Array.from(ins1).forEach(element => {
      element.addEventListener('click', callback);
    });
  }

  const ins1 = $("ins[data-ad-slot]");

  // pre-made second div for future replacement
  const ins2 = document.createElement('ins');
  ins2.param = '9020596432';
  ins2.innerText = 'ins2';

  replaceAfter3Clicks(ins1, ins2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ins data-ad-slot="4092520690">ins</ins>
```

Comment: `$("data-ad-slot")` should be `$("ins[data-ad-slot]")`

Comment: `$("data-ad-slot")` looks for `<data-ad-slot>`

Comment: thanks! might of overlooked that one. if there are more problems with the code, please enlighten me, as i'm not as experienced with javascript

Comment: i've updated the code so it's more readable lol.

Comment: You don't need the `Array.from...` code. Just `ins1.click(callback);`

Comment: You're missing the closing `}` for the function.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the close brace for `let callback = function() {...`. Also, `elem` is a jQuery object, not a DOM element, so you can't use `parentNode`. jQuery has a `replaceWith()` method that can be used to replace an element directly.

```js
function replaceAfter3Clicks(elem, newElem) {
  let count = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("ins_count") || "0");
  let callback = function() {
    count++;
    sessionStorage.setItem("ins_count", count);
    if (count >= 3) {
      elem.replaceWith(newElem);
    }
  }
  ins1.click(callback);
}

const ins1 = $("ins[data-ad-slot]");

// pre-made second div for future replacement
const ins2 = document.createElement('ins');
ins2.param = '9020596432';
ins2.innerText = 'ins2';

replaceAfter3Clicks(ins1, ins2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><ins data-ad-slot="4092520690">ins</ins></div>
```

Comment: Amazing stuff! Thanks for helping me. Now, would it be possible to make this work for sessionStorage aswell. So the webserver remembers the change and doesn't return to its default state. Whether in the database or in Cookie, sessionStorage, localStorage.

Comment: Yes, every time you increment count, you can do `sessionStorage.set("ins_count", count);`. And initialize it `let count = parseInt(sessionStorage.get("ins_count") || "0")`

Comment: I changed those lines with what you've suggested, and it doesn't seem to work. Could you maybe update your post with sessionStorage assignment to it, for a bit more detail. Maybe, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: I got the function names wrong, they're `getItem` and `setItem`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: There seem to be some more errors. ```Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag."```

Comment: That's a restriction of Stack Snippets. It should work on your site.

Comment: I have put it on a page of my website https://natevanghacks.com/hacks/autisticware2.php But it doesn't seem to function it returns back to ins and when you retry, it doesn't log the 3 clicks anymore. Might be because of something to add aswell. EDIT: It does work but doesn't change the value to ins2, lol i'm a goofball.

Comment: I've changed it to `>= 3` because it keeps incrementing after you refresh the page. Or if it's above 3 when the page loads, you should just replace `ins1` with `ins2` immediately.

Comment: Replaced the code on the site yeah, when you refresh you gotta click one more time for it to change. In layman terms, I think a slight change needs to be done.